# Java RMI freezes while calling a function on a stub

Tags: java, maven, rmi, freeze

## Summary

I am working on a project and found this problem:

We have found a problem in our code that we cannot solve.
First we give some general information about the Eclipse project and how it can be executed, then we give some details about the code and finally we describe the problem.

## The project

We built a Java Maven project in Eclipse. It contains two source folders: src/main/java and src/test/java. The main folder contains an implementation of the Gallager's, Humblet's and Spira's algorithm. At this moment we have one test SimpleTest to see whether basic functionalities of the algorithm works as expected.
The code can be executed as follows:

1. Unzip the attached file DA-Lab3.zip.
2. Open a command/terminal window in the folder DA-Lab3/target/classes.
3. Start the Java RMI Registry in this directory (“rmiregistry &” in Linux, "start rmiregistry" in Windows).
4. Go to the folder DA-Lab3 in the command/terminal window.
5. Execute: “mvn clean install -f .”.  (If this does not work because maven cannot clean a folder, try the same command without “clean”.)
   Now the testfiles should be executed by Java / Maven.

## The code

The code is split up into several parts. The most important parts to understand are Node, Process and RMINetwork.
Node contains the actual algorithm, Process extends Node with practical functions like creating edges, implement the sending method and removing edges. RMINetwork handles RMI-related functions like registering a process in the registry, unregister a process, and looking up other processes in the RMINetwork.

Node is placed in the GHS.graph package. The package also contains Edge, NodeState and EdgeState.
Messages are handled by the receive function (row 221). Each type of message implements the interface GHS.messages.IMessage with the function process. The receive function in Node calls this process function in each message. From these process functions in the messages particular functions in Node are called. These functions in Node process messages according to the algorithm.

Process is placed in the package GHS. It extends Node with a id variable and the functions send, connect, disconnect, id(), run and stop. The send function determines the id of the receiver and give the RMINetwork the task to send a message to the receiver.
The Process class also implements the IProcess interface. This interface is used by RMI clients.

RMINetwork is placed in the package communication. This class contains functions  to register, unregister, lookup and send.

## The problem

In SimpleTest test1 three processes and one edge are created. Process 0 connects to process 2. Then process 0 wakes up and sends a connect message to process 2. Process 2 wakes up and sends a connect message back to process 0. Then process 0 send an initiate message to process 2. But here, Java seems to freez without throwing any errors.

To step into detail:
Java seems to stuck at: `((IProcess) this.lookup(id)).receive(edge, message);` RMINetwork r: 52.

To see what the actual problem is, we added some test code to the function.
At row 49 we added: `IProcess p = (IProcess) this.lookup(id);`
And row 50: `String s = p.id();`
Row 51: `System.out.println("networking");`
With this test code enabled Java stucks at row 50.

When row 50 is disabled, row 51 is executed and Java stucks at row 52.

The p.id() function is implemented in Process. The first statement prints a string to the command line. At the moment that Java stucks, this print statement is not executed.

When we replace row 49 with 49 we added: `IProcess p = (IProcess) this.lookup(edge.neighbour(id));` (the sender is now actually looking up its own id), then the problem happens while sending the second instead of the third message.

So it seems that Java RMI freezes at a call on a stub. But it always works for the first message and, depending on row 49, for the second message. Because no error is thrown we have no idea why RMI freezes at this point.

```
@Override
public void send(String id, Edge edge, IMessage message) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("testing");
    IProcess p = (IProcess) this.lookup(id);
    String s = p.id();
    //System.out.println(((IProcess) this.lookup(id)).id());
    System.out.println("networking");
    ((IProcess) this.lookup(id)).receive(edge, message);
    System.out.println("id found");
}
```

We hope you can help us out.

You can view all code on: https://github.com/mboom/DA-Lab3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the processes were waiting for each other in a single thread. Old initiated methods, that send messages to other processes, were not finished yet at the moment another process called a method via a stub. These methods will not start as long as the old methods are running. Because the old methods were waiting for a response (that only comes when these old methods are finished), the system ended up in a deadlock. We solved the issue by executing the receive method of nodes in a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

The remote method you invoked isn't returning.

Comment: In this case Java freezes on `String s = p.id();` and it should return the id of the process (see https://github.com/mboom/DA-Lab3/blob/master/src/main/java/GHS/Process.java row 66). Therefore, I am not sure what you mean. Do you think some unexpected behaviour occurs causing the id() function not returning?

Comment: That's not where it says you are freezing in your question, but whatever you are calling, it isn't returning, as I already stated. NB I have finally figured out that when you say 'row' you mean 'line'. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I am sorry about the terminology :(. Thanks for your answer.